# Joomla CSS: Increasing menu size to parent div

Tags: html, css, joomla

Small problem on my Joomla site.

I have added a menu module that is not displaying in full on the site. Its in a  that is configured to be 100% of the screen.

But with the menu when I try to make it 100% of the screen it is cut on both sides.

Where could I find where is the menu configured?

Or how should I start with it?

```
<body id="body">

    <div id="siteWrapper">
        <header id="header">
            <div class="wrapper container">
                <div class="siteLogo"></div>
                <div class="ol_clearFR"></div>
                <div id="mainMenu">
                    <div class="moduletable">
                        <ul class="jb_free_dropdown jb_free_dropdown_111"></ul>
                    </div>
                    <div class="moduletable">
                        <ul class="jb_free_dropdown jb_free_dropdown_105">
                            <li class="item-126 current active"></li>
                            <li class="item-118 parent"></li>
                            <li class="item-122">
                                <a href="/joomla/index.php/service"></a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="item-123"></li>
                            <li class="item-124"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="cleartBoth"></div>
            </div>
        </header>
```

CSS FROM DROPDOWN:

```
@charset "UTF-8";


ul.jb_free_dropdown,
ul.jb_free_dropdown li,
ul.jb_free_dropdown ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding:0 ;
  font-family: Tahoma, Geneva,sans-serif;
    text-align: left;
    vertical-align: middle;

}
/*This is for menu item links by Nejc Vukovic*/


ul.jb_free_dropdown li.item-124
{
    margin-right:1px;
    float:right;
    background: #FFFFFF;

}
ul.jb_free_dropdown li.item-126 {border-style:none}

ul.jb_free_dropdown.jb_free_dropdown_105 
{width:100%;}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li.item-118 a:after {
  content:url(../../../../images/trianglegrey8x4.png);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li.item-122 a:after {
  content:url(../../../../images/trianglegrey8x4.png);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}


ul.jb_free_dropdown li.item-123 a:after {
  content:url(../../../../images/trianglegrey8x4.png);
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
    padding-left:10px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 597;
  float: left;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li {
  float: left;
  min-height: 1px;
  line-height: 1.3em;
  vertical-align: middle;
   margin-left:1px;

}


ul.jb_free_dropdown li.hover,
ul.jb_free_dropdown li:hover {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 599;
  cursor: default;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown ul {
  visibility: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 598;
  width: 100%;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown ul li {
  float: none;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown ul ul {
  top: 0px;
  left: 100%;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li:hover > ul {
  visibility: visible;
}


/* -- Base drop-down styling -- */

ul.jb_free_dropdown {
  font-weight: bold;
}

    ul.jb_free_dropdown li {
     padding: 7px 10px;
     border-style: solid;
     border-width: 1px 1px 1px 0;
     border-color: #fff #d9d9d9 #d9d9d9;
     background-color: #f6f6f6;
     color: #000;
}

    ul.jb_free_dropdown li.hover,
    ul.jb_free_dropdown li:hover,
    ul.jb_free_dropdown li.on {
     background-color: #eee;
     color: #000;
    }

    ul.jb_free_dropdown a:link,
    ul.jb_free_dropdown a:visited   { color: #000; text-decoration: none; }
    ul.jb_free_dropdown a:hover     { color: #000; background-color: #ececec;}
    ul.jb_free_dropdown a:active    { color: #000000; }

    /* -- level mark -- */

    ul.jb_free_dropdown ul {
     width: 100%;
     margin-top: 1px;
    }

        ul.jb_free_dropdown ul li {
         font-weight: strong;
        }






ul.jb_free_dropdown a,
ul.jb_free_dropdown span {
 display: block;
 padding: 1px 10px;
 background: #f4f4f4;
    width: 100%;
}


/* -- Base style override -- */

ul.jb_free_dropdown li {
 padding: 0;
 border: none;
}

/*
JB
*/
ul.jb_free_dropdown li li.parent a {
  background: #FFFFFF('../../media/images/arrow.png') right 10px no-repeat;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li li.parent li a {
  background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li.parent a:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li li.child a {
    background: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li.active a {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;

}
ul.jb_free_dropdown li.active li a {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;


}
ul.jb_free_dropdown li.active li a:hover {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}



/*
JB
*/
ul.jb_free_dropdown ul a,
ul.jb_free_dropdown ul span {
 padding: 1px;
    width: 100%;
 display: block;
    border-width: 5px;
 border-style: ridge;
    border-color: #F8F8F8;
-moz-border-radius: 2px; /* FF1+ */
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px; /* Saf3-4 */
          border-radius: 2px;
}


/* -- Base style reinitiate: post-override activities -- */

/* -- Custom styles -- */

ul.jb_free_dropdown li.hover,
ul.jb_free_dropdown li:hover {
 content: url(../../../../images/trianglegrey16x8.pn) 0 100% repeat-x;
 color: #000;
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li:hover {
  color: #F8F8F8;
}

ul.jb_free_dropdown li a:active {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
}
ul.jb_free_dropdown li a:link{background-color: #FFFFFF}
ul.jb_free_dropdown li a:visited{background-color: #FFFFFF}

ul.jb_free_dropdown

/* -- Mixed -- */

ul.jb_free_dropdown li a,
ul.jb_free_dropdown *.dir {
 border-left-style: solid;
 border-width: 1px;
 border-left-color: #E8E8E8;
}

/* -- Drop-down open -- */
```

AND TEMPLATE CSS:

```
/* CSS Document */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'ol_icons';
  src: url("../fonts/ol_icons.eot");
  src: url("../fonts/ol_icons.eot?#iefix") format('embedded-opentype'), url("../fonts/ol_icons.woff") format('woff'), url("../fonts/ol_icons.ttf") format('truetype'), url("../fonts/ol_icons.svg#ct_icons") format('svg');
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
}

body {
    background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

p {
    margin: 10px 0 12px 0;
}
a {
    color: #369;
}
a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
  background-color: #F8F8F8;
}

a:focus {
    outline: none;
}

h1, h1 a, h1 span, 
h2, h2 a, h2 span, 
h3, h3 a, h3 span,
h4, h4 a, h4 span,
h5, h5 a, h5 span,
blockquote {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5 {
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5), 0px -1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

h1 a, h2 a, h3 a, h4 a, h5 a {
    cursor: pointer;    
}
#header{background: rgba(255,255,255,0.7);}
.row > div,
.row_main > div,
.error {
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
header{
     z-index: 50000;
}
.page-header {
    bordr: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    width100%;
}

blockquote {
    font-size: 18px;
    font-style:italic;
    line-height: 19px;
}

#main img {
    border:medium none;
    margin:0 10px 0px 0;
    max-width:100%;
    outline:meium none;
}

.ol_imgRaw {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0; 
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

.collapse {
    -moz-transition:heigt 0.35s ease 0s;
    height:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    position:relative;
}
/* logo  ------------------------------- */
.textLogo { font-size: 35px; } 
.slogan { font-size: 12px;} 


/* LISTS  ------------------------------- */

ul, ol {
    margin: 1em 0;
    padding: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    margin-left: 15px;
} 

li {
    line-height: inherit;
}

ul li {
    margin-left: 0;
}


ul.category {
    list-style: none inside none;
}

ul.category li {
    padding: 7px;
}

ul.ol_squareList,
ul.ol_arrowList, 
ul.ol_starList, 
ul.ol_checkList {
    list-style: outside;
}


ul.ol_arrowList         {list-style-image: url(../images/ul_arrow.png);}
ul.ol_arrowList.back    {list-style-image: url(../images/ul_arrow_black.png);}
ul.ol_arrowList.white   {list-stye-image: url(../images/ul_arrow_white.png);}


ul.ol_checkList         {list-style-image: url(../images/ul_check.png);}
ul.ol_checkList.black   {list-style-image: url(../images/ul_check_black.png);}
ul.ol_checkList.white   {list-style-image: url(../images/ul_check_white.png);}


ul.ol_arrowList li, ul.ol_starList li, ul.ol_checkList li  {
    background: non;
}

ul.ol_arrowList li ul,
ul.ol_starList li ul,
ul.ol_checkList li ul,
ul li ul li ul, ul li ul li ul li ul {
    margin-left: 13px;
}


/* SLIDER -------------------------------------*/

#ol_headerWrapper {
    position: relaive;
    z-index: 30;
    height: auo;
    overflow: visble;
    margin: auo
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#ol_headerContent{
    position: rlative;
    height: aut;
    margin: auo;
    -webkit-border-radius: px;
    border-radius: 10px; 
}

/* Flash header -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */
#mx-headerout { background-color: #6e6e6; margin-top: -15px;    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    box-shadow: 0 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);

    -pie-box-shadow: 0 0px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15)}
#mx-header { margin-bottom: 1px; padding: 0px; }
/* Mobile */

@media handheld, only screen and (max-width: 940px) {

#mx-header { display: none; }

}


/* Copyright -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

#copyright { margin-top: 0.5em; margin-bottom: 0; padding: 10px;float:right;}
#copyright p { margin-bottom:0; }
#copyright ul {  margin:0; padding: 1.2em 0 0; }
#copyright ul li { float:left; list-style:none; background: none; }
#copyright ul li a { display:block; color: #1F1F1F; }
#copyright ul li.active a, #copyright ul li a:hover, #copyright ul li:hover a, #copyright ul li.sfHover a { color: #0099FF;  text-decoration:none; }

/* MODULE POSITION CONTAINERS -------------------------------------*/

.cleartBoth {
    clear: both;
}

.ol_clearFL {
    clear: left;
}

.ol_clearFR {
    clear: right;
}

.cleartBoth,
.ol_clearFL,
.ol_clearFR {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}


.ol_module, .ol_left {
    float: left;
}

.ol_right {
    float: right;
}


/* TABLE STYLES ------------------------------------------*/

.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) td, 
.table-striped tbody tr:nth-child(2n+1) th {
    background: none;
}

.table th, .table td {
    border-top: none;
}
#siteWrapper {
color: #333;
}
/* MODULE BOX STYLES -------------------------------------*/

.moduletable {
    height: auto;
}

.ol_left .moduletable, 
.ol_right .moduletable,
.ol_left .moduletable_ol_dark, 
.ol_right .moduletable_ol_dark,
.ol_left .moduletable_ol_light, 
.ol_right .moduletable_ol_light,
.ol_left .moduletable_ol_red, 
.ol_right .moduletable_ol_red,
.ol_left .moduletable_ol_green, 
.ol_right .moduletable_ol_green, 
.ol_left .moduletable_ol_blue, 
.ol_right .moduletable_ol_blue {
    padding: 10px;
}

.moduletable_ol_dark, 
.moduletable_ol_light, 
.moduletable_ol_red, 
.moduletable_ol_green, 
.moduletable_ol_blue {
    width: auto;    
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;     
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25); 
    box-shadow:0 1px 4px rgba(0,0, 0, 0.25);
    -pie-box-shadow: 0 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.moduletable_ol_light {
    color: #333;
    background-color: #fff !important;
}

.moduletable_ol_dark {
    color: #ccc;
    background-color: #333 !important;
}

.moduletable_ol_red {
    color: #f1f1f1;
    background-color: #cc0000 !important;
}

.moduletable_ol_green {
    color: #f1f1f1;
    background-color: #339933 !important;
}

.moduletable_ol_blue {
    color: #f1f1f1;
    background-color: #336699 !important;
}

/* LINKLIST ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.moduletable_ol_linkList a {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    border: none;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 15px;
    padding: 5px 0 5px 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
    width: auto;
    background-image: url(../images/icon_link_arrow.png);
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position:  center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
    cursor: pointer;
}


/* VOTING / RATING ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.content_vote {
    margin: 5px 0;
}

.content_vote input[type="radio"] {
    margin: 0 2px 0 3px;
}

.content_vote input.button {
    display: inline;
    text-align: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    height: 23px;
    width: auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:normal;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    text-shadow:0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
    padding: 2px 7px 7px 7px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}


/* ACTIONS PANEL (PRINT & E-MAIL) ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.actions {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: inside none;
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}

.actions > li {
    float: left;
}

.actions > li {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    overflow: hidden;
    white-space: nowrap;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 7px;
}

.actions li > a > i {
    font-size: 18px;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
}

.print-icon a,
.email-icon a,
.edit-icon a {

}

.print-icon a img, .email-icon a img, .edit-icon a img{
    opacity: 0;
        -moz-opacity: 0;
        -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=0)";
        filter:alpha(opacity=0);    
}


i.tip {
    z-index: 0 !important;
    max-width: auto;
    padding: 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 0;
    border-radius: 0; 
    background: none;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}

.print-icon > a > i,
.email-icon > a > i,
.edit-icon > a > i,
.print-icon > a:hover > i,
.email-icon > a:hover > i,
.edit-icon > a:hover > i {
    background-image: none !important;
    margin-right: 5px;
}

.print-icon > a,
.email-icon > a,
.edit-icon > a {

}

.print-icon > a > i:before, 
.email-icon > a > i:before,
.edit-icon  > a > i:before {
    font-family: 'ol_icons';
    font-style: normal;
}

.print-icon > a > i:before{ content: '\e716'; } /* '' */
.email-icon > a > i:before { content: '\2709'; } /* '✉' */
.edit-icon  > a > i:before { content: '\270d'; } /* '✍' */



#ocpanel {
    padding: 10px;
    clear: both;
    font-size: 37px;
    left: 40%;
    top: 45%;
    position:absolute;
    color: #888;
    display: block;
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
}

/* LOGIN -----------------------------------------*/

#login-form p {
    margin-top: 5px;
}

.ol_logins {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 0;
    padding-left: 14px;
    list-style: outside;
    list-style-image: url(../images/icon_link_arrow_small_hover.png);
}

.ol_logins li {
    width: 100%;
}

.ol_logins li a {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-decoration: none;
}

#form-login-remember {
    display: block;
}

#form-login-remember label, 
#form-login-remember input {
    float: left;
}

#form-login-remember label {
    line-height: 19px;
}

#form-login-remember input {
    clear: right;
}

#login-form .button {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
    margin-top: 10px;
    display: inline-block;
}

.login-fields {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.login .button {
    margin-top: 5px !important;
}

.logout-button .button {
    margin: 0 !important;
    float: none !important;
}

.login-greeting {
    height: 25px;
    font-size: 14px;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-right:15px;
}

/* COMPACT VERSION FOR HEADER */

#login-form.compact, 
#login-form.compact fieldset
{
    width: auto;
}

#login-form.compact p {
    padding: 0 !important;
    margin-top: 0 !important;
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}

#login-form.compact #form-login-username label, 
#login-form.compact #form-login-password label, 
#login-form.compact #form-login-remember, 
#login-form.compact .ol_logins 
{
    display: none;
}

#login-form.compact input[type="text"], 
#login-form.compact input[type="password"]
{
    width: 120px;
    height: 25px;
    margin-right:5px;
    padding-left: 7px;
}

#login-form.compact .button
{
    margin: 0;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 !important;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 25px;
    padding: 0;
    padding-bottom: 1px;
    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 25px;
}

#login-form.compact .button 
{
    float: none;
    clear: none;
    margin-top: 0;
}

/*-----------------*/

/* RESET / REMIND / REGISTRATION */

.reset, .remind, .registration {
    max-width: 460px;
    white-space: normal;
}


.reset .form-actions, 
.remind .form-actions, 
.registration .form-actions {

}

/* HEADER SEARCH ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

#ol_hIn h3 {
    display: none;
}

#ol_hIn label, 
#ol_hIn .finder label {
    visibility: hidden;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

#search #mod-search-searchword, 
#search .finder input {
    width: 200px;
    padding-left: 30px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

#ol_hIn .search input, 
#ol_hIn .finder input {
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    height:25px;
    padding-left:30px;
    width:200px;
}

.autocompleter-choices {
    border: none !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    overflow: visible !important;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-left: -5px !important;
}
.autocompleter-choices li {
    margin:10px !important;
    background: #00ff00;
}

.autocompleter-choices {
    border: none !important;
    margin-top: 5px !important;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    overflow: visible !important;
    width: auto !important;
    margin-left: -5px !important;
}
.autocompleter-choices li {
    margin:10px !important;
    background: #00ff00;
}

/* PAGENAV ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/ 

ul.pagenav {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    margin: 25px auto;
    clear: left;
}

ul.pagenav li {
    list-style:none outside none;
    background-image: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

ul.pagenav li a { 
    margin-top: 20px !important;
}

ul.pagenav li.previous a,
ul.pagenav li.next a {
    float: left;
}


/* GLOBAL TABLE STYLES  ------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

table.category th, table.category td {
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 7px;
}

table.category {
    width: 100%;
}

table.category th {
    padding: 5px 10px 5px 0;
}

table.category th, table.category th a {
    text-align: left;
    font-family: "MavenProRegular", "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
}

table.category th a img {
    margin-left: 5px;
}

table.category th, table.category td {
    padding: 5px;
}


/* SYSTEM MESSAGES -------------------------------------------- */

.alert-info {
    background-color: transparent;
    border-color: transparent;
    color: inherit;
}

.alert,
#system-message > dd { 
    text-indent: 45px;
}

.alert,
#system-message dd.message ul,
#system-message dd.error ul,
#system-message dd.warning ul,
#system-message dd.notice ul,
.bfErrorMessage {
    background-position: left top !important;
    border: none;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px; 
    padding-left: 0 !important;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.alert,
#system-message > dd.message ul li,
#system-message > dd.error ul li,
#system-message > dd.warning ul li,
#system-message > dd.notice ul li,
.bfErrorMessage {
    color: #ff3600 !important;
    font-size: 14px !important;
}

.alert-heading {
    color: #ff3600 !important;
    font-size: 18px !important;
    font-weight: bold;
}


/* TOOLTIP ----------------------------------------------------- */

.tip-wrap {
    z-index: 1981 !important;   
}

.tip {
    padding: 5px 10px 10px 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px; 
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

.tip-title {
    display: inline-block;
    font-weight: normal !important;
    margin: 0 0 5px 23px;
    padding: 0;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 18px;
}

.tip-text {
    font-size: 12px;
}


/* BADGES --------------------------------------------------------------*/

.badge {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 20px;
    min-width: 10px;
    padding: 0 5px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 20px;

    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
}

/* BLOG-FEATURED ------------------------------------------------------ */

.blog-featured h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.blog-featured h2 {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}


/* BREADCRUMBS ------------------------------------------------------ */

.ol_breadcrumbs {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin: 10px;
}

.ol_breadcrumbs span, .ol_breadcrumbs a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.ol_breadcrumbsSeparator {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 7px !important;
    background: url(../images/icon_link_arrow_small_hover.png);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

/* LINKS ---------------------------------------------------*/

.ol_inlineLink {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 12px;
    font-weight: 600;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin: 0 5px;
    padding: 0 9px 2px 0;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    background-color: transparent;
    background-position:  center right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}

a.readmore,
p.readmore a,
.ol_customLink {
    display:block;
    font-size:12px;
    font-weight:bold;
    letter-spacing: 0.05em;
    min-height:19px;
    line-height:14px;
    padding: 5px 7px 1px 7px;
    position:relative;
    text-decoration:none;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

a.readmore,
p.readmore a {
    float: left;
}


/* ERROR PAGES ---------------------------------------------------*/

.error {
    padding: 20px 0;
}

#ol_errorWrapper {
    display: block;
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.errorNumber, #errorboxheader {
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}

.errorNumber {
    text-shadow: 1px 3px 3px rgba(0,0,0, 0.5);
    font-size: 100px;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

#errorboxheader {
    font-size: 26px;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

#errorboxbody {
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

#errorboxbody ul {
    list-style: none;
}

#errorboxbody a {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 0;

    text-decoration: none;
    border: none;

    font-size: 14px;

    text-shadow: 0px -1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

    cursor: pointer;

    -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
    -moz-border-radius: 2px;
    border-radius: 2px;

    background-position: right;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;

    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    -pie-box-shadow: 0 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15); 

    height: 25px;
    line-height: 22px;
    padding: 4px 12px 1px 12px;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
}

#mailto-window { padding: 10px 20px; }




/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-width : 321px)
and (max-width : 786px) {

    #main .colWidth_11 img {
        float: none;
    }
}



/* ADMIN / EDIT ---------------------------------*/

#adminForm .tab-content {
    overflow: visible;
}

#ol_errorWrapper, #ol_errorWrapper a {
    color: #369;
}

body,
body.contentpane,
#errorboxheader,
#errorboxoutline {
    color: #333;
}

/* BASIC ELEMENTS ------------------------------*/

a:hover,
#ol_logins li:hover a,
.ol_breadcrumbs a:hover,
a.readmore:hover, 
p.readmore a:hover,
.categories-list span.item-title a:hover,
.category td a:hover,
.category th a:hover,
.registration legend,
.search-results .result-title:hover,
.search-results .result-title:hover a,
ul.circleList li, 
ul.circleList li ul li,
.errorNumber
{
    color: #cc0000;
}

.row > div > h1:after,
.row > div > h2:after,
.row > div > h3:after,
.row > div > h4:after,
.row > div > h5:after {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

Comment: It's possible that the menu is contained within your site wrapper which might be a set width. If you provide a link to your site, it will be easier to give  more accurate answer

Comment: Can you please provide your HTML an CSS?

Comment: Quick question: I know there is a site where you can post code into and then it is displayed in workspaces? Link?

Comment: This is probably one of the most common sites to post the code: http://jsfiddle.net/